# How to find total DOM processing and page rendering time in chrome

Tags: dom, google-chrome-devtools, webpage-rendering

How to find total DOM processing and page rendering time in chrome for a particular page (running locally) .. i want to see the total time for the entire page and not individual resources in the page.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Timeline function in the developer tools in Chrome. Alternativly you can also use the Profiler if you want to watch memory usage or the Network tab to view downloading and rendering of the page.